# Get last id from a group of foreign key with Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I have a relation with primary key named idavaliacao and foreign key named trabalho_idtrabalho, and I want to get the last tuple for each foreign key order by idavaliacao, desc.
Eg:

```
idavaliacao | trabalho_idtrabalho  
------------+--------------------  
     1      |         1  
     2      |         1  
     3      |         2  
     4      |         3  
     5      |         3   
     6      |         4
```

returns:

```
idavaliacao | trabalho_idtrabalho  
------------+--------------------  
     2      |         1  
     3      |         2  
     5      |         3   
     6      |         4
```

Eloquent Queries:

```
$ids = Trabalho::where([['trabalho.eventos_ideventos',$evento->ideventos],['eixos_tematicos_ideixos_tematicos',$id_eixo]])->get(['trabalho.idtrabalho'])->toArray();

$avaliacao = Avaliacao::whereIn('trabalho_idtrabalho',$ids)->to be continued
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `HasOne` [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) to your `Trabalho` model:

```
public function avaliacao() {
    return $this->hasOne(Avaliacao::class, 'trabalho_idtrabalho', 'idtrabalho')
        ->orderByDesc('idavaliacao');
}
```

Then use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$trabalho = Trabalho::where([['trabalho.eventos_ideventos',$evento->ideventos], 
       ['eixos_tematicos_ideixos_tematicos',$id_eixo]])->with('avaliacao')
   ->get(['idtrabalho']);

$avaliacao = $trabalho->pluck('avaliacao');
```

Comment: It work but in the example I didn't especify that i have another columns in the Avaliacao table. So when I put them in the addSelect I get an error:   Grouping error: 7 ERROR: column "avaliacao.descricao" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...(idavaliacao) idavaliacao, "trabalho_idtrabalho", "descricao... Can You help me?

Comment: I replaced my answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the answer-

```
select * from yourtable t1 
where t1.idavaliacao =
(select max(idavaliacao) from yourtable t2 where t2.trabalho_idtrabalho=
                    t1.trabalho_idtrabalho)
```

Check here-http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41d3c6/22